# Coverting input to lowercase

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i need to convert a text input and array into lowercase so when entered it can be matched against the array. I keep getting errors saying airline.Array.contains is not a function. Can anybody help please.

```
var euAirlines = [
      "British Airways",
      "Austrian Airlines",
      "Blue Islands",
      "KLM",
      "TAP Portugal",
      "Air Malta",
      "Air France",
      "germanwings",
      "Wideroe",
      "Lufthansa",
      "Aegean Airlines",
      "Citywing",
      "Flybe",
      "Aurigny",
      "airBaltic",
      "Swiss",
      "eurowings",
      "Croatia Airlines",
      "SAS",
      "LOT",
      "Air Serbia",
      "Iberia",
      "Wizz Air",
      "Blue Air",
      "easyJet",
      "Air Europa",
      "Czech Airlines",
      "Aer Lingus",
      "Eastern Airways",
      "Smart Wings",
      "Aeroflot",
      "Thomson Airways",
      "bmi regional",
      "Ryanair",
      "Monarch",
      "TAROM",
      "Brussels Airlines",
      "Jet2",
      "Meridiana",
      "Vueling Airlines",
      "CityJet",
      "Scilly Skybus",
      "Alitalia",
      "Thomas Cook Airlines",
      "Garuda Indonesia",
      "Norwegian",
      "Ukraine International",
      "Bulgaria Air",
      "Finnair",
      "Luxair"
    ];

    Array.prototype.contains = function (needle) {
       for (i in this) {
           if (this[i] == needle) return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    var airlineInput = document.getElementById("airlineInput"),
      airlineArray = euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase();
    document.getElementById("claim-submit").onclick = function(e) {
      var lower = airlineInput.value.toLowerCase();
      console.log(lower);
      if (airlineArray.contains(lower.value)) {

       console.log("Match");
      }else {

        console.log("No Match")
      }

    }
```

Comment: that's because it's not an array ... `airlineArray = euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase();` does not do what you think

Comment: airlineArray i want all the array values to be lowercase then check against the text input.

Comment: add `.split(',')` after `toLowerCase()`

Comment: airlineInput is getting the element not the value of text.
use this: document.getElementById('airlineInput').value.toLowerCase();
and  airlineArray = euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase()  to  euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase().split(',')

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a new list that lowercases the airlines like so.

```
var lowercaseEUAirlines = euAirlines.map(function(airline) {
    return airline.toLowerCase();
});
```

You could then easily iterate over it using a forEach:

```
lowercaseEUAirlines.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write contains for array as string already has a includes function. You can use like this.

```
var lowerCaseArrayString = euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase();
if(lowerCaseArrayString.includes(lower)){
  console.log("matched");
}else{
  console.log("not matched");
}
```

or if you still want to do with array then you can use this.

```
var lowerCaseArray = euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase().split(",");
if(lowerCaseArray.indexOf(lower) > -1){
  console.log("matched");
}else{
  console.log("not matched");
}
```

Comment: It's not `contains` but [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: @R3tep well yes i checked. `Includes` is much better as it supports all browser but firefox still has `contains` method for string including `includes`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible here is what you are searching:

```js
var euAirlines = [
      "British Airways",
      "Austrian Airlines",
      "Blue Islands",
      "KLM",
      "TAP Portugal",
      "Air Malta",
      "Air France",
      "germanwings",
      "Wideroe",
      "Lufthansa",
      "Aegean Airlines",
      "Citywing",
      "Flybe",
      "Aurigny",
      "airBaltic",
      "Swiss",
      "eurowings",
      "Croatia Airlines",
      "SAS",
      "LOT",
      "Air Serbia",
      "Iberia",
      "Wizz Air",
      "Blue Air",
      "easyJet",
      "Air Europa",
      "Czech Airlines",
      "Aer Lingus",
      "Eastern Airways",
      "Smart Wings",
      "Aeroflot",
      "Thomson Airways",
      "bmi regional",
      "Ryanair",
      "Monarch",
      "TAROM",
      "Brussels Airlines",
      "Jet2",
      "Meridiana",
      "Vueling Airlines",
      "CityJet",
      "Scilly Skybus",
      "Alitalia",
      "Thomas Cook Airlines",
      "Garuda Indonesia",
      "Norwegian",
      "Ukraine International",
      "Bulgaria Air",
      "Finnair",
      "Luxair"
    ];

var checking = function (e, val) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('body').append($('<p>').text($.inArray(val, euAirlines) > -1 ? 'Match' : 'Not match')) 
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="airlineInput" onkeyup="checking(event, $(this).val().toLowerCase())" />
```

To test my example: Input `Germanwings`, or `Eurowings` and press enter to check.

Answer (score 0):

You have converted the array to a string (`airlineArray = euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase()`), and a string does not have the property `contains`.

You appear to want to check if there is a (partial) match for the input in the airlines array. If that's the case, you could use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the matching elements, and [`String.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find if it matches, like this:

```js
var euAirlines = [
    "British Airways",
    "Austrian Airlines",
    "Blue Islands",
    "KLM",
    "TAP Portugal",
    "Air Malta",
    "Air France",
    "germanwings",
    "Wideroe",
    "Lufthansa",
    "Aegean Airlines",
    "Citywing",
    "Flybe",
    "Aurigny",
    "airBaltic",
    "Swiss",
    "eurowings",
    "Croatia Airlines",
    "SAS",
    "LOT",
    "Air Serbia",
    "Iberia",
    "Wizz Air",
    "Blue Air",
    "easyJet",
    "Air Europa",
    "Czech Airlines",
    "Aer Lingus",
    "Eastern Airways",
    "Smart Wings",
    "Aeroflot",
    "Thomson Airways",
    "bmi regional",
    "Ryanair",
    "Monarch",
    "TAROM",
    "Brussels Airlines",
    "Jet2",
    "Meridiana",
    "Vueling Airlines",
    "CityJet",
    "Scilly Skybus",
    "Alitalia",
    "Thomas Cook Airlines",
    "Garuda Indonesia",
    "Norwegian",
    "Ukraine International",
    "Bulgaria Air",
    "Finnair",
    "Luxair"
];

function containsLowerCaseMatch(needle, value) {
    return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}

var airlineInput = document.getElementById("airlineInput");
var matches = euAirlines.filter(containsLowerCaseMatch.bind(null, airlineInput.value));

if (matches.length > 0) {
    console.log('Match');
} else {
    console.log('No match');
}
```

*The code also uses [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to pass the entered text.*

## Full example with autocomplete

```js
var euAirlines = [
  "British Airways",
  "Austrian Airlines",
  "Blue Islands",
  "KLM",
  "TAP Portugal",
  "Air Malta",
  "Air France",
  "germanwings",
  "Wideroe",
  "Lufthansa",
  "Aegean Airlines",
  "Citywing",
  "Flybe",
  "Aurigny",
  "airBaltic",
  "Swiss",
  "eurowings",
  "Croatia Airlines",
  "SAS",
  "LOT",
  "Air Serbia",
  "Iberia",
  "Wizz Air",
  "Blue Air",
  "easyJet",
  "Air Europa",
  "Czech Airlines",
  "Aer Lingus",
  "Eastern Airways",
  "Smart Wings",
  "Aeroflot",
  "Thomson Airways",
  "bmi regional",
  "Ryanair",
  "Monarch",
  "TAROM",
  "Brussels Airlines",
  "Jet2",
  "Meridiana",
  "Vueling Airlines",
  "CityJet",
  "Scilly Skybus",
  "Alitalia",
  "Thomas Cook Airlines",
  "Garuda Indonesia",
  "Norwegian",
  "Ukraine International",
  "Bulgaria Air",
  "Finnair",
  "Luxair"
];

function containsLowerCaseMatch(needle, value) {
  return value.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) > -1;
}

var airlineInput = document.getElementById("airlineInput"), suggestions = document.getElementById("suggestions");

airlineInput.onkeyup = function() {
  suggestions.innerHTML = '';

  var matches = euAirlines.filter(containsLowerCaseMatch.bind(null, airlineInput.value)).forEach(function(value) {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));
    suggestions.appendChild(li);
  });
};

airlineInput.onkeyup();
```

```html
<input id=airlineInput name=airlineInput>
<h1>Suggestions</h1>
<ol id=suggestions></ol>
```

You will obviously need to adapt it to your codebase.

Comment: It does however have an 'includes()' if using modern enough browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: @NeilMunro I know, but the code I provided is supported in IE9+. Also, it allows you to provide autocomplete functionality (which I imagine the OP is planning to do) without any significant changes or duplication.

Answer (score 0):

Just use mapping:

```
newArray = map(function(s){s.toLowerCase()}, oldArray)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [**@NeilMunro**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33871105/3210837).

Comment: I assume you meant to write `newArray = oldArray.map(function(s){s.toLowerCase()})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var euAirlines = [
      "British Airways",
      "Austrian Airlines",
      "Blue Islands",
      "KLM",
      "TAP Portugal",
      "Air Malta",
      "Air France",
      "germanwings",
      "Wideroe",
      "Lufthansa",
      "Aegean Airlines",
      "Citywing",
      "Flybe",
      "Aurigny",
      "airBaltic",
      "Swiss",
      "eurowings",
      "Croatia Airlines",
      "SAS",
      "LOT",
      "Air Serbia",
      "Iberia",
      "Wizz Air",
      "Blue Air",
      "easyJet",
      "Air Europa",
      "Czech Airlines",
      "Aer Lingus",
      "Eastern Airways",
      "Smart Wings",
      "Aeroflot",
      "Thomson Airways",
      "bmi regional",
      "Ryanair",
      "Monarch",
      "TAROM",
      "Brussels Airlines",
      "Jet2",
      "Meridiana",
      "Vueling Airlines",
      "CityJet",
      "Scilly Skybus",
      "Alitalia",
      "Thomas Cook Airlines",
      "Garuda Indonesia",
      "Norwegian",
      "Ukraine International",
      "Bulgaria Air",
      "Finnair",
      "Luxair"
    ];
   var new_euAirlines_lowercase=euAirlines.toString().toLowerCase().split(',');
    Array.prototype.contains=function(input_value){
     new_euAirlines_lowercase.forEach(function(value,index){
      if(value == input_value)
       console.log('matched')
         else
        console.log('did not match')
    });
  }

    $('#claim-submit').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var input= $("#airlineInput").val().toLowerCase();
        Array.prototype.contains(input);
   });
```

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/gnnf86jh/